# I constantly get this error when creating APK in React native application

Tags: javascript, react-native, build, apk, gradlew

I constantly get this error when creating APK in React native application.
Could you please help?
I have tried all of the codes below.

1. react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file
   index.js --bundle-output
   android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
   android/app/src/main/res
2. gradlew clean
3. gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets or gradlew
   bundleRelease

   FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

   ```
   1: Task failed with an exception.
   -----------
   * What went wrong:
   Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
   > C:\Users\Emre Can\Desktop\ReactNative\bulutmd\android\app\src\main\res\drawables\launch_screen.png: Error: The file name must end with .xml

   * Try:
   > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
   > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
   > Run with --scan to get full insights.
   ==============================================================================

   2: Task failed with an exception.
   -----------
   * What went wrong:
   java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

   * Try:
   > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
   > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
   > Run with --scan to get full insights.
   ==============================================================================

   * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

   Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

   You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

   See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

   BU¦LD FAILED in 2m 46s
   159 actionable tasks: 127 executed, 32 up-to-date
   PS C:\Users\Emre Can\Desktop\ReactNative\bulutmd\android> 
    *  History restored 


   Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

   PS C:\Users\Emre Can\Desktop\ReactNative> cd bulutmd
   PS C:\Users\Emre Can\Desktop\ReactNative\bulutmd> cd android
   PS C:\Users\Emre Can\Desktop\ReactNative\bulutmd\android>
   ```

Comment: Similar to https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/432

Answer (score 0):

guys i have fixid this error using react native old version 0.68.0....
newer version of react native are fixing this problem like
0.70.2,0.70.2 are
so plz change your project with old version,hope this guide helps you..